# JSONExtractInt64 null extract from string into clickhouse

Tags: json, null, clickhouse

I have a source table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.source
(
    text_json String
)
    engine = Memory;
```

I have a destination table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.destination
(
    column Nullable(Int64)
)
    engine = Memory;
```

I insert to the source:
`INSERT INTO test.source (text_json) FORMAT JSONAsString {"column": null};`

Then I try to parse json int value and insert into destination

```
INSERT INTO test.destination (column)
SELECT JSONExtractInt(text_json) FROM test.source;
```

However, it will insert 0. And it will be a non-deterministic behavior as if I have a real zero beforehand, it will be impossible to differentiate between `NULL` and 0.

How to parse from `JSONString` null value into Int64 column AS `Null`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON_VALUE](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/#json_valuejson-path) to extract the string value and pass that to INSERT instead (with implicit or explicit casting):

```
INSERT INTO test.destination (column)
SELECT JSON_VALUE(text_json, '$.column')
FROM test.source
```

The result will be NULL:

```
SELECT * FROM test.destination
┌─column─┐
│   ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└────────
```

Comment: but what type will it insert in case of `INT`? I guess `STR`, but I wanted `INT`

Comment: It will insert the same type that is contained in the table, in this case `Nullable(Int64)`